# Tracing in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I read the following statement when covering Autographs and Tracing in Tensorflow.

> TensorFlow will only capture for loops that iterate over a tensor or a
> dataset. So make sure you use for i in tf.range(x) rather than for i
> in range(x), or else the loop will not be captured in the graph.
> Instead, it will run during tracing.
> (This may be what you want if the for loop is meant to build the graph, for example to create each layer in a neural network.)

I am confused as to what exactly happens. If it runs during tracing how it not registered on the graph but also how would the for loop build the graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example which shows the difference between a `tf.range` loop and a `range` loop:

```
for i in tf.range(3):
  x = tf.add(x, i)
```

results in a graph which contains a `tf.while_loop` that matches the `for` loop; this is the translation that AutoGraph makes:

```
def cond(i, x):
  return tf.lesss(i, 3)
def body(i, x):
  x = tf.add(x, i)
  return i, x
tf.while_loop(cond, body, ...)
```

In turn:

```
for i in range(3):
  x = tf.add(x, i)
```

results in a graph which contains a three `tf.add` calls, and `i` is substituted by constants, without any loop ops:

```
x = tf.add(x, 0)
x = tf.add(x, 1)
x = tf.add(x, 2)
```